# Problema com o método mágico __get

Tags: php

Estou tentando recuperar o valor de uma propriedade privada da minha classe utilizando o método mágico  __get. Segundo a documentação do PHP, toda vez que eu tentar acessar uma propriedade privada ou protegida de uma classe, ela ira disparar o __get. Porém, ele não está sendo executado.

```
class Test{

    private $conexao;

    private static $connectionInstance;

    public function __get($valor){
        echo '13';
        if($valor === "conexao"){
            if(!isset($this->conexao)){
                $this->conexao = new stdClass;
            }
            return $this->conexao;
        }else if($valor === "conexaoo"){
            if(!isset($this->conexao)){
                $this->conexao = new stdClass;
            }
            return $this->conexao;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance(){
        if(self::$connectionInstance === null){
            self::$connectionInstance = new Test;
        }
        return self::$connectionInstance;
    }

    public static function problem(){
        $instance = self::getInstance();

        return $instance->conexao;
    }
}

$test = new Test;

var_dump($test::problem());
```

No código acima, sempre que tento acessar **conexao** de dentro do método **problem**, ele não dispara o método __get, porém, se eu substituir **conexao** por **conexaoo**, que é uma propriedade não declarada, ele dispara o método.

Alguém pode me explicar o motivo?

Comment: Ele só dispara o método `__get` quando quem está acessando não tem acesso ao campo. Como você está acessando o campo de dentro da própria classe, você terá acesso ao campo privado e, assim, não há porque chamar o *método mágico*.

Comment: Nesse caso, ele vai ignorar o fato de serem instancias diferentes?

Comment: Sim, porque não importa qual é a instância, mas sim que está acessando o campo dentro da própria classe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graças a ajuda nos comentários consegui chegar a resposta.

O problema é que, independente da instancia, como se trata da mesma classe, o método __get nunca será disparado, pois a própria classe possui acesso a suas propriedades privadas, não dependendo assim do método mágico.

Agradeço ao Woss pela explicação.